# What is the name of this indirect grill?

Tags: language, grill

[image]

In Japanese, it seems to be called a Machuugrill. It is fired by charcoal and the grill arrows are just air. It seems to be some convection heating with the temperature moderated by water. Translation dictionaries don't include it all. What is closest term for this grill?

Comment: Given that it may be uniquely Japanese, probably Machuugrill. I've certainly never seen anything like it. I suspect the straight and sharply bent arrows are actually to indicate direct and reflected radiant heat from the coals, while the curved ones indicate hot air/smoke. Interesting idea, though the benefit is not obvious.

Comment: It's basically a smoker, similar to the Webster bullet style

Comment: If the blue bit is water it might not have a specific term in English. Otherwise in English the term is probably something like "wood-fired oven" because assuming no smoke, then that's essentially what you have. You might modify it to "wood-fired humidified oven" with the water.

Comment: Is it an oven when it is so open? Don't they ladle water onto BBQs?

Comment: water on bbqs? no. bbq is typically dry heat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grill in question seems to be the [Loyly Smokeless BBQ](https://www.loyly-bbq.com/products/muen-bbq-grill) (「ロウリュ」無煙バーベキューグリル *"Rouryu" muen bābekyū guriru*), a proprietary device by a [Japanese company of the same name](https://www.loyly-bbq.com/) and intended primarily for camping use or for charcoal grilling in small outdoor spaces.

These are not particularly common even in Japan, in fact I'd never heard of this concept before.  "Smokeless grills" are a common product category, but the term usually refers to electric or battery-operated grills, not this unusual charcoal-and-steam combo.